# SQL Server Authentication behaves differently under different service accounts

Tags: sql-server, service-accounts

I have an application, which needs to run on Windows under a given service account. The .NET application connects to an MSSQL database and in the connection string I have specified the SQL server authentication used, namely

```
<add name="conn" connectionString="Data Source=(localdb)\MSSQLLocalDB;initial catalog=MyDB;User Id=testuser;Password=xxx" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
```

If I run SSMS under my regular domain account, then I can use the SQL user 'testuser' to connect to the database. However, if I run SSMS under the service account that should run the application, then I receive "Login failed".
(And the same happens when running the service).

I've spent more than a day looking into this problem, so if anyone has any ideas what might be wrong, I would very much appreciate it.

**Update:**
The error message in the SQL server log is

```
07/12/2017 12:18:32,Logon,Unknown,Login failed for user 'testuser'. Reason: 
Could not find a login matching the name provided. [CLIENT: <named pipe>]
07/12/2017 12:18:32,Logon,Unknown,Error: 18456<c/> Severity: 14<c/> State: 5.
```

But if I log onto SSMS using my domain account, 'testuser' is listed under Security --> Logins.

The SQL Exception that happens, when I try to start the service, is

The service did not start successfully
System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException (0x80131904): Login failed for user 'testuser'.
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlInternalConnectionTds..ctor(DbConnectionPoolIdentity identity, SqlConnectionString connectionOptions, SqlCredential credential, Object providerInfo, String newPassword, SecureString newSecurePassword, Boolean redirectedUserInstance, SqlConnectionString userConnectionOptions, SessionData reconnectSessionData, DbConnectionPool pool, String accessToken, Boolean applyTransientFaultHandling)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnectionFactory.CreateConnection(DbConnectionOptions options, DbConnectionPoolKey poolKey, Object poolGroupProviderInfo, DbConnectionPool pool, DbConnection owningConnection, DbConnectionOptions userOptions)

I've omitted some of the stacktrace, because it was quite long.

Comment: I've updated the question with the log output. Thanks for your time!

Comment: `(localdb)` is local to a specific user. Use `sqllocaldb share` (from the command line) to expose an instance that is available across users.

Comment: This makes a lot of sense! I ran the command 
     _sqllocaldb share "MSSQLLocalDB" "SharedLocalDB"_
followed by 
    _sqllocaldb info_
which resulted in
    _.\SharedLocalDB,
    MSSQLLocalDB,
    ProjectsV13_

Now if I specify 
    _(localdb)\SharedLocalDB_
in the connection string, I get the error "A network-related or instance-specific error occurred while establishing a connection to SQL server. The server was not found or was not accessible".

Comment: That's because you didn't read carefully enough :-) The instance name *includes the period and backslash*, and so the full name is `(localdb)\.\SharedLocalDB`.

Comment: If I use `(localdb)\.\SharedLocalDB` then I get the exact same error :(

Comment: It was a stupid user error. For some reason the localdb instance had stopped, when I fiddled with it yesterday. Now it works! Thanks so much :) Could you perhaps create an answer such that I can acknowledge it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`(localdb)` is local to a specific user. Use `sqllocaldb share` (from an elevated command prompt) to expose an instance that is available across users:

```
sqllocaldb share MSSQLLocalDB SharedLocalDB
```

If the instance is running, it needs to be restarted before the shared instance is available:

```
sqllocaldb stop MSSQLLocalDB
sqllocaldb start MSSQLLocalDB
```

You can now connect to the shared instance as `(localdb)\.\SharedLocalDB` (mind the extra `.\`).

Note that LocalDB's intended use is testing in isolation, without having to manage SQL Server (indeed, there are very few options for managing it). If you need a database instance that's available continuously, you're better off installing an SQL Server Express instance.